# How to get auto.arima(trace=TRUE) as an object?

Tags: r, arima

I was searching throughout google about this but didn't get any clue, the closest clue I get is with this papermail https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2011q4/008681.html but I didn't get any point of it. So I was thinking the only way is to manipulate `auto.arima()` function, can somebody manipulate this function?

I really need this to get information of best second model from the trace, to replace the best model (which is white noise) to do arima computation manually. Thank You for your time :)

Like for example:

```
> auto.arima(ts,trace=T)

 ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean : Inf
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean : 365.0674
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : 367.4462
 ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : 367.4406 <<- (I Need to get this)
 ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean     : 381.969
 ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean : 367.4462
 ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean : 367.4406
 ARIMA(1,0,1) with non-zero mean : 369.1222

 Best model: ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean
```

Comment: You may check the code and perhaps change line 433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paraphrasing from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2011q4/008681.html):

```
trace <- capture.output({
    # assign so it doesn't pollute the output
    model <- auto.arima(ts, trace = TRUE)
})
con    <- textConnection(trace)
models <- read.table(con, sep=":")
close(con)
```

Answer (score 0):

add '''error action: 'trace' ''' in auto.arima settings.

‘trace’: Logs the entire error stacktrace and continues the
search. This is the best option when trying to determine why a model is failing

source: https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html